# HTML colors & margins rendering differently (same code, css & browser)

Tags: html, css, nginx, margins, php

enter image description herei have a grid of divs that are spaced margin-left:13px.  When you view the site on herokuapp.com it looks correct (13px margin).  When i view it on my own in house server its 17px even though the css & code are identical.  When i inspect the elements with chrome it shows the 13px margin and an unexplained addition of 4px that i cant seem to track down anywhere!

The background color is different too, Hex code is the same (#F2D900)...  I assume it has to be my webserver (since its the only difference), but i had no idea that the web server could affect the way a page is rendered client side?

Anyone ever heard of this?

my server is:
- nginx 1.2.1
- php-fpm (though the page has no php code)
running on: Amazon AMI ec2)

correct [image]

wonkey  [image]

Comment: How different is the color?  The monitors could be calibrated very differently, which can cause significant color shift.  How do you know it's a different number of pixels?  Is the screen resolution the same on both systems? Add some screen-shots demonstrating the differences.

Comment: @JimGarrison same monitor :\ windows are side by side both using chrome.

Comment: If you're receiving the same hex code (verified with Firebug or similar in the DOM, not the HTML) in two windows of the _same browser_, side-by-side on the same physical monitor, and are getting different colors... well it's Halloween and your monitor is haunted.  Post a screenshot so we can marvel at this madness.

Comment: You can upload the pictures using the editor, click the 6th icon from the left.

Comment: There we go!  The yellow slab at the bottom is what i noticed was a different color.

Comment: It's definitely different. Any chance you're sending a file with a different colorspace, or the browser's default colorspace is set to, say AdobeRGB instead of sRGB?

Comment: Thats a good point, i cant actually say if the images have been properly tagged but, the yellow strip is actually a square div with background: #F2D900... would the webserver be sending along different color space information you think?  I snapped the shots on the same browser window, just different tabs

Comment: Ahh, ok i did some cross browser testing and it seems to be just chrome thats causing the color shifting.  I'll have to investigate the colorspace topic a bit more.  Any idea about the haunted margin?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that you have some kind of artifacts somewhere on the page generated by server. This can affect how margins look somewhere on the website.

Comment: This is not an answer; should be a comment.